# Django-Gunicorn-Nginx Why do I get an Internal server error every time I restart Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I set up a droplet on digital ocean using the [one-click installer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image). I host my code on a git repo. and I use `git pull` to merge changes, followed by `service gunicorn reload` to restart gunicorn. The problem is that everytime I do this and try to visit my site I get an `'internal server error'` messages, and after I refresh once or twice the actual page loads.

It is strange because I get the message even if I wait for a while (15 minutes) before visiting the web page, so I'm not sure if I get this because gunicorn was still restarting or for some other reason. Any hints on what might be going on ?

Comment: Just curious, does it do the same thing if you restart nginx as well?

Comment: Nope, only when I restart gunicorn

Comment: Gotcha. I don't know if it's related, but DigitalOcean has been having some connectivity issues with their NYC2 node for the past few days. If you're connected to that one and this issue has just started, you might try creating a droplet on the London node and seeing if that helps. Wish I had something more helpful, sorry.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution yet @potatoes? I'm also using Digital Ocean.

Comment: Nope @MarkWinterbottom I'm thinking of raising the issue on DO forums since they might have an answer

Comment: Here's the question @MarkWinterbottom https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/django-gunicorn-nginx-why-do-i-get-an-internal-server-error-every-time-i-restart-gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

`--graceful-timeout` or `graceful_timeout`
Otherwise the workers will stick around until the next request seemingly.
When set to `0` will cause the workers and the master to instantly quit.

Hope it helps.